# I'm trying to identify this frame. Any help is appreciated

Tags: identify-this-bike

I found this abomination and bought it because I thought it looked cool, but I want to restore it so I would love to know what the end product should look like.[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  I think you probably intended to include a picture?  Can you [edit] your post so we can see the bike you're talking about?

Comment: Is there any writing on it at all?

Answer (score 2):

The more I look, the weirder that gets.

It is clearly someone's homemade project bike, build on top of some kind of workman's frame or "heavy rider" frame.

---

Underneath is a dual top-tube frame, that looks to be made of steel tubing.   The joints appear to be butt-welded and not lugged, which implies **newer than the 1980s**

The head-tube angle is ridiculously steep, within a few degrees of vertical.  This frame would have the handling of a shopping cart, and would be extremely twitchy to ride with no self-centering characteristics.

The front fork also looks home-made.  It has a kind of bow-suspension whose design has been around for a hundred years, but this one is clearly added by hacking up an existing fork and inserting a compression spring.

There is a brake, but only one, and it is a flat metal stamped caliper that can't even reliably stop a child's bike.  If you do ever ride this, consider upgrading the front brake and adding a rear brake.

Wheels - the rims have the colouration of aluminium, meaning they're from the `90s or newer.  Sizing is hard to gauge but they look like 26"   Reading the sidewall of the tyres might yield a little more info.

The rear drive is interesting - clearly the bike started with conventional gears but someone removed the derailleur hanger and mech.  The cassette has been left in place but can't be used because chain is only one length.  So the rear wheel has had the motor drive cog retrofitted.

The cranks are probably part of the liquid-motor kit, so nothing noteworthy there, other than they're low-grade ashtabula one-piece design.

The saddle has also been cobbled together with an extra support frame and relocated further aft.  This allows a lower, stretched out body posititon for aero reasons, but discourages power for pedalling.

---

This bike is intended to be foot-pedalled to about 10 mph or 15 km/h with the liquid motor idling, and then the clutch is let out.  This is likely a 49cc single cylinder petrol engine, and does not have the torque to start the bike+rider from stopped, hence "pedal up to speed"

Depending on your local laws, this may not be classed as a bicycle.  Here in New Zealand that would be a "mo-ped" and requires the rider to have a valid car driver's licence.  The bike would not be legal as it needs that second brake, and also requires lights, and the muffler has to reduce the sound to a under a specific level.

It MIGHT classify as a pedal bicycle if the motor were not running, but still needs another brake.

Answer (score 1):

It's not totally dissimilar to a Schwinn B10e.

I don't know much about these (ask someone in the US!) but I'm fairly sure it's a Schwinn. Front tyre is a supporting clue.  It's probably a retro reproduction of a classic model. Try scouring their old catalogues. I will try and posta  link if I  have time later.

[image] 
  <sup>Source: https://thecabe.com/forum/threads/1933-schwinn-b10e-built-by-the-pedal-pusher-newport-beach-ca-restored-in-1980.197822/</sup>

Comment: Probably something inspired by some Schwinn, certainly not that B10e.

Comment: You're right its definitely similar but also not quite the same.   Curiously, both appear to be lug-free designs, so brazed with no obvious external joint reinforcement.  For a 1930's era bike, that's quite noteworthy.   On the other side, the head tube angle is way different, and the lower-top tube meets the downtube at the headtube compared to OP's bike where the lower top tube is only joined to the downtube.

Comment: The front suspension is similar but has a spring rather than simply relying on flexation.   Definitely relevant and an excellent find !